# Why the java code isn't showing proper number of instances?

Tags: java, class, oop, junit, annotations

I was following the [Java tutorial](https://youtu.be/grEKMHGYyns) on freecodecamp and I wrote the following code.
Here, I created two classes : PersonTest.java and Person.java. I have written 3 tests in PersonTest.java.
While writing first two tests, two instances of Person class have been created. In the third test which counts the number of instances created; I am getting the output as 1 (I expect it to be 2). I am not getting why is it showing so. Any help is appreciated :)

**PersonTest.java**

```
package com.atharvajoshi.javacourse.lesson2;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

public class PersonTest {
    @Test
    public void shouldReturnHelloWorld() {
        Person atharva = new Person();                  // First instance
        assertEquals("Hello World", atharva.helloworld());
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnHelloAtharva() {
        Person person = new Person();                   // Second instance
        assertEquals("Hello Atharva", person.hello("Atharva"));
    }


    @Test
    public void shouldReturnNumberOfPersons() {
        System.out.println(Person.numberOfPersons());   // Answer is coming to be 1
        assertEquals(2, Person.numberOfPersons());      // Test failed
    }
}
```

**Person.java**

```
package com.atharvajoshi.javacourse.lesson2;

public class Person {

    private static int personCounter = 0;

    public Person() {
        personCounter ++;
    }

    public String helloworld() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    public String hello(String anyName) {
        return "Hello " + anyName;
    }

    public static int numberOfPersons() {
        return personCounter;
    }
}
```

Output : 1

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Fijb.png)

Comment: Does [this](https://onlinegdb.com/HyyYA3T38) help?

Comment: @Mandy8055 Yes, thank you for the help. Can you please tell me why am I getting numberOfPersons = 1 ? I am not getting what is wrong with my code.

Comment: The unit test methods do not run in the same order as they are in source code. It may be possible to force them to run in order, but it would be best to write the test methods in a way that doesn't depend on other tests having been run

Comment: @Joni I didn't know this! I was struggling to find what was wrong with my code. Thank you!

Comment: Please paste the output as text into your question.

Comment: @NomadMaker  Yes. The output is coming as 1. I have written it at the bottom and I have also attached the screenshot for your reference.

Comment: @Joni I suggest you make an Answer of your Comment, so this page can be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't specify an order in JUnit, then the order of execution of the tests are arbitrary. for visualizing this, add a sysout of "inside method XX" in your code. if you are using an IDE, add a debugger and debug the PersonTest java class, you will know the order of execution is arbitory. if you use junit 4.x and above, then try this annotation

@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)

This will execute the test cases in the alphabetical order of method names